# How to Reverse A String in a loop

Tags: python, string, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I am writing a program to do convert a decimal number into binary, using repetitive division. I just can't reverse the final answer (which is variable "x").

```
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))

    remainder = 0
    while num > 0: 
        remainder = num%2
        num = num//2
        x = str(remainder) 
        #print(reversed(x))
    
        print(x[::-1])
```

output for num = 19

```
1
1
0
0
1
```

which is reversed from the actual answer, which is 10011 for decimal 19.
Also, how can I bring the answer all in one line, so its not written vertically

Comment: You can also directly convert a decimal to a binary number using `bin(num)`

Answer (score 2):

You are just printing the binary numbers one at a time in the loop, you can't relay reverse when they are printed one after another like that.

You could instead insert the binary elements in a list like this

```py
num = 19

remainder = 0
binary = []
while num > 0: 
    remainder = num%2
    num = num//2
    binary.insert(0,str(remainder))

print("".join(binary))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))

s = ''
remainder = 0
while num > 0:
    remainder = num%2
    num = num//2
    s += str(remainder)

print(s[::-1])
```

You were reversing individual digits, i.e."1", "0" instead of the whole final string. Obviously, reversing strings with length 1 does not do anything.

Alternatives:

```
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))

s = ''
while num:
    bit = num & 1
    s += str(bit)
    num >>= 1

print(s[::-1])
```

Or simply:

```
print(bin(int(input("Enter a number: "))))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the newline after a `print` by doing:

`print(x[::-1], end='')`